# How can I divide two strings in Ruby with gets.chomp?

Tags: ruby, integer-division

I try to divide two strings. Here's the code:

```
puts "Enter a weight in lbs: "
lbs = gets.chomp
stconversion = 14
stone = lbs / stconversion
puts "That is #{stone} stone"
```

I keep getting this error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/lbs to stones.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined method `/' for "14\n":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: You can not divide two strings. Reason for error

Comment: Always say what error you get, never say "I got an error". Read the error message. sometimes it is helpful.

Comment: `gets.chomp.to_f.round(2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `gets` stands for "get a string". You are trying to divide a string by a number.

Change the line

```
lbs = gets.chomp
```

to

```
lbs = gets.chomp.to_i
```

to convert the string to an integer, or use `to_f` if you prefer using floats.

Comment: This is over kill don't need to use `gets.chomp.to_i` can use `gets.to_i`

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** divide a `string`, you need to convert it to an `int`, i.e.:

```
stone = lbs.to_i / stconversion.to_i
```

Or convert a `string` to a `float`:

```
stone = lbs.to_f / stconversion.to_f
```

Comment: int ? What language is this? Also, this does integer division in ruby, 13/14 results in 0.

Comment: You use `str.to_i`in ruby

Comment: @ppperry in this case `to_f`may be a better choice.

Comment: Unless integer division is specifically requested, assume that a float is required, which you might then convert. Dependiing on requirements, that might be  `lbs.to_f/stconversion`, `(lbs.to_f/stconversion).round(n)`, `(lbs.to_f/stconversion).floor` (or `to_i`) or `(lbs.to_f/stconversion).ceil`.

Comment: @steenslag You're right. the reason I used `.to_i` is because the OP used the python `int` function instead of the `float` function.

Answer (score 0):

Its over kill to utilize `lbs = gets.chomp.to_i` when you can simply utilize `lbs = gets.to_i`  This is the proper way of handling it.

`puts "Enter a weight in lbs: "
lbs = gets.to_i
stconversion = 14
stone = lbs / stconversion
puts "That is #{stone} stone"`